# Given two independent standard normal variables $X, Y\!,$ and $W= X+ Y, Z= X- Y\!,\!$ seek $\mathbb{E}\left [ X+ 2Y\mid Z \right ]$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation, independence

> Given two independent standard normal variables $X, Y\!,$ and $W= X+ Y, Z= X- Y\!,\!$ seek $\mathbb{E}\left [ X+ 2Y\mid Z \right ]\!.$

*Attempt*. We obtain
$$\mathbb{E}\left [ X+ 2Y\mid Z= z \right ]= \mathbb{E}\left [ X+ 2Y\mid X- Y= z \right ]= \mathbb{E}\left [ \left ( Y+ z \right )+ 2Y \right ]= 3\mathbb{E}\left [ X \right ]+ Z= Z\!.$$
Is this correct ?

Comment: "Is this correct?" Not at all. As a preliminary step, you might want to compute $E(3W-Z\mid Z)$.

Comment: $E[2X+4Y|Z]=E[3W-Z|Z] = 3E[W|Z]-Z = (2Y+Z)-Z$?

Comment: Yes, except that $3E(W|Z)\ne 2Y+Z$ (what makes you think this would hold?).

Comment: Sorry, that should have been: $3E(W|Z) = 3(2Y+Z)$ and hence $E[X+2Y|Z]=  0.5(6Y+2Z) = 3Y+Z$. Correct?

Comment: ?? Why E(W|Z)=2Y+Z?

Comment: $E[W|Z] = E[X+Y|X-Y] = E[X|X-Y]+E[Y|X-Y] = ?$

Comment: This is correct, and what is E[X|X−Y]+E[Y|X−Y]?

Comment: $X+Y$? I am not sure, because this is where I am having issues comprehending it. E[X|X-Y] = $\int x f_{X|X-Y}dx$

Comment: Surely you have some definition of E[X|X-Y] at hand, more convincing than the horror in your last comment?

Comment: $f_{X|X-Y} = \frac{f(x,x-y)}{f{x-y}}$ $X-Y$ and $X$ are both normal with 0 mean. But then $X$ and $X-Y$ are not independent.

Comment: Once again: how does one **define** E[X|X-Y]?

Comment: I think I have out down everything I could think of. If you could help, that would be great.

Comment: The question is simple: given two random variables U and V defined on the same probability space, U integrable, how does one define E(U|V)?

Comment: That should be $E[U]$ then if $U,V$ are independent, which is not the case here

Comment: Alright, reading more on bivariate normals, $E[W|Z] = \frac{\rho \sigma_W}{\sigma_Z}Z$ Where $\rho = \frac{E[WZ]}{\sigma_W\sigma_Z}$ and here $E[WZ] = E[X^2-Y^2]=0$

Comment: @Did Does the above comment make sense?

Comment: It does, and indeed E(W|Z)=0 in the case at hand, although it carefully avoids to answer the specific query in mine.